# What is the proper way to automate use of ElementTree in Python?

Tags: python, xml

I am using Python to generate some XML files which are used by another device.  I have a solution which works but I am trying to improve it.  One of the things which the XML must contain is a schedule.  Here is what the entry for Monday should look like in XML.

```
<Monday open="08:00" close="17:00" />
```

I have no problems generating this with ElementTree in Python but right now I am stuck having a line of code for each day.  So a snippet of my Python code looks like this:

```
SubElement(schedule, 'Monday', open='08:00', close='17:00')
SubElement(schedule, 'Tuesday', open='08:00', close='17:00')
.
.
.
SubElement(schedule, 'Sunday', open='08:00', close='17:00')
```

The XML file will wind up having multiple schedules in it and typing all of that out seems needlessly repetitive.  Instead of this I wanted to create a function which iterates over a list to build up the parameters to pass to SubElement.  As part of that function I created this string to replace the times in my SubElement call.

```
"open=" + "\'08:00\'" + ", " + "close=" + "\'17:00\'"
```

If I print this out it looks identical to what I pass to SubElement when I type out the code the long way.  However it clearly isn't the same as I get the following error when I try to run the script.

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 528, in SubElement
   attrib = attrib.copy()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

I have looked at the SubElement code and it seems to be expecting a dictionary.  However, when I type things out the long way I don't appear to be supplying a dictionary as input then either so I can't see why the function should accept that input but not the string which appears, to me, to be equivalent.  Is there any way to do what I am trying to do or am I stuck with a lot of repetitive lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a dictionary of attributes instead of "string of attributes" to SubElement, something like:

```
SubElement(schedule, 'Sunday', {'open': '08:00', 'close': '17:00'})
```

or

```
times = {'open': '08:00', 'close': '17:00'}
SubElement(schedule, 'Sunday', times)
```

Comment: This works great.  I still don't quite get why it's required though.  On one hand it certainly satisfies the dictionary input requirement of SubElement and from that standpoint it does make sense.  On the other hand SubElement seemed quite happy when I used it in this form:  'SubElement(schedule, 'Monday', open='08:00', close='17:00')'  This doesn't look like a dictionary to me and yet I got no errors when I used it.  Why should it work this way at all?  It seems like if you needed a dictionary as input you would always have to supply input in that form.

Comment: `SubElement` interprets all "unknown" keyword arguments as key-value pairs for the attribute dictionary, which means that `SubElement(a, "b", attrib={"c": "d"}, e="f")` is equal to `SubElement(a, "b", {"c": "d", "e": "f"})`